# How to add a content type field to a SPList using PowerShell

Tags: powershell, content-type, spfield

This the scenario:

I have created a new LookupField (Content Type) called MyLookupField which derives from SPFieldLookup as shown below:

```
public class MyLookupField : SPFieldLookup
{
  ...
}
```

Here's my question: With PowerShell how do I create a SharePoint list column using my new content type MyLookupField which derives from SPFieldLookup? 
The method to add column to a list in PowerShell expects an enumeration which is obviously does not have my derived MyLookUpField field.

```
$myList.Fields.Add("MyLookup", [Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFieldType]::?????,$true)
```

With PowerShell how do I create a SPList column and associate it to a content type?

Answer (score 0):

```
$web = Get-SPWeb <url>

$childList = $web.Lists["Employees"]    
$parentList = $web.Lists["Countries"]

$childList.Fields.AddLookup("Country", $parentList.ID, $true)

$field = $childList.Fields.getfield("Country")

$fieldLink = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFieldLink($field)

$ctype = $childList.ContentTypes["MyLookupField"]

$ctype.FieldLinks.Add($field)

$ctype.Update()
```